# Why do we have to prove $1+1=2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, intuition

I have 0 knowledge on number theory, but I currently have to take a course about proving.

So I wonder why do we have to prove something that is "trivial", in the sense that we are using it, without noticing it in everyday life?
What is the significance of proving such statements?
Like the well-ordering principle, $1+1=2$, etc.

Comment: Mostly to teach young mathematicians how to prove things, and to reinforce the habit and necessity of proving *everything*, because not all things that seem obviously true are indeed true.

Comment: And another thing. High school math and every day math teaches us to think about numbers and other mathematical objects in a rather concrete way while they nature is somewhat more abstract. By studying the properties of these objects from basic axioms and definitions, we break our old, flawed intuition and develop a better intuition.

Comment: We don't have to, but if our foundations have some hope of being useful, you better hope we can prove $1+1=2$ with them!

Comment: [It's far more difficult to prove that 1+1 cannot also be equal to 5.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Consistency)

Comment: @CountIblis - this is not correct; to prove *consistency* of arithmetic is to prove that we **cannot** prove e.g. $0=1$.But we can easily prove that $0 \ne 1$,because $1=S(0)$ and by Peano axiom : $\forall x \lnot S(x)=0$ from which, by instantiation : $\lnot S(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The [Well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) is not so "trivial".

About the proof of $1+1=2$ it is trivial to prove it from [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) and some definitions :

1) $0$ is a natural number --- Axiom

2) for all natural number $n, \ S(n)$ is a natural number --- Axiom, where $S(n)$ is the *successor* of $n$

3) for all $n, \ n+0=n$ --- Axiom for sum

4) for all $n, m \ n+S(m)= S(n+m)$ --- Axiom for sum

5) $1=S(0)$ --- definition of $1$

6) $2=S(1)=S(S(0))$ --- definition of $2$

Thus :

> $1+1=S(0)+S(0)=S(S(0)+0)=S(S(0))=2$.

---

In general, in mathematics we "like" to prove statements, also (if possible) the most "elementary" ones.

Comment: Note that this exact proof generalizes to $n+1 = S(n)$, which probably what you'd expect from adding one :)

Answer (score 2):

Historically, there have been many "trivial" things that turned out to be wrong. You can only be sure about an assertion if you have a proper definition and a proof using that definition.

To the Greeks it was "obvious" that every number was a quotient of two integers; until they bump on the fact that the length of the diagonal of a square of side one cannot be such a quotient.

The Well Ordering Principle is actually not liked by a good number of mathematicians. It seems simple enough, but it turns out to imply many assertions that are not that easy to take (namely, the Axiom of Choice, Zorn's Lemma and all their implications). So accepting well-order implies accepting a whole bunch of not-obvious-at-all things.

People in general and mathematicians have been using numbers for a very long time. But, like I mentioned, not everything is so rosy: if you want to talk about $\sqrt2$, they you need to tell me what kind of object it is (and for a start, you could try to explain what "number" is). This problem took mathematicians a very long time to sort out.

There are also versions of this in analysis and algebra, too.

Finally, the assertion "$1+1=2$" in itself means nothing. You need to define what the symbols, $1$, $+$, $=$, and $2$ mean. There are several ways of doing that. In some (me preferred point of view), "$2$" is **defined** to be $1+1$ (or, more properly, $S(S(0))$ as Mauro mentions in his answer. If you define the integers in some way and you define what it means to add them, then you need to prove that $1+1=2$.

Comment: I think the well-ordering principle referred to in the question is "$\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered", which is comparatively uncontroversial.

Comment: Don't confuse the "well-ordering theorem" with the "well-ordering principle."

Comment: So I have another question. These kinds of things should have been proved at the modern era.(I'm not sure) What comes to mathematician head that "ah! These statement may not be as obvious as we think, and we have to prove it"? People in before have used them many many times and take them for granted. What happened at that changing point?

Comment: @mathshungry - this is correct for arithmetic... But the first extant book of math, *Euclid's Elements* are a book axiomatizing geometry, i.e. proving from "basic" principles other well-known geometrical "facts", like Pythagoras' theorem, already known to Egyptians and Babylonians.